# D3 code linking to php file outputs the actual code as text on the web page

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I am trying to use d3 code to output a simple graph using dates and TCP upload information that come from my database using php. I can output my json data correctly, but whenever i try to run my html file, it outputs the code as text and no graph at all. I have tried looking for different solutions, but nothing seems to work. I even switched from aptana to using cloud 9 and nothing seems to output a graph. I have a feeling it might have to do something with the d3 code or the link to the d3 library, but I am totally lost. Here is my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d\/%b\/%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.TCP_UP); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


   d3.json("capstone/connection.php", function(error, data) {
   data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
    d.TCP_UP = +d.TCP_UP;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.TCP_UP; })]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

//});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it is based off this code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5).

In the example posted [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html), I was merely just supposed to switch the data.cvs file with my php file, so I don't know if that could be a problem as well. Thanks! Let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you forgot to open the script code. Place a `<script>` tag between the code and the script tag that loads d3.

Comment: Thanks for catching my stupid mistake! I am filled with them.

Comment: Oh well, we all make them sometimes